# How to install a SONY Tablet S as an ADB device?

Tags: android

I need to install a Sony Tablet S as a ADB device, so that I could debug it.

I've done as explained here - http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/support-info.pl?info_id=878

but still it does not show up as an ADB device. On the other hand, in the Device Manager it shows in Portable Devices / Sony Tablet S , as a MTP Device. If I uninstall it and then plug it back in, it will automatically install as a MTP Device.

**Any idea, how can I dis-associate it from being an MTP Device and associate it with ADB ?**

Thanks!

p.s. if I use update driver ... have disk and point to android_winusb.inf , it'll say "The folder doesn't contain a compatible software driver..."

Answer (score 14):

I experienced the same ***after performing the steps given the below link*** as mentioned in question,

http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/support-info.pl?info_id=878

But then i fixed it as follows,

1. You should see **Sony Tablet** in 'Other devices' in **Device Manager**.
2. Ensure that adb is killed. (no "adb.exe" process in Task Manager)
3. Double click the "Sony Tablet" in Device manager.

And follow the steps in the upcoming windows..

- Click Reinstall driver
- No, Not this time --> Next
- Install from a list or specific location --> Next
- Click "Include this location in this search"
- Browse to this path in your machine,
  **android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver**
- Click Next

It will detect "Android Composite ADB Interface" and drivers will be installed.

Check **adb devices** in command prompt, you should see device listed.

Comment: step 3 must be device manager instead of task manager ;) for the rest it works fine, stupid that sony didn't include this part in their explanation...

Comment: I had to dig deeper and install the driver by specifying the inf file directly...android_winusb.inf.

Answer (score 1):

did you check:

settings ==> applications ==> USB debugging?

Comment: if you install driver, then restart PC, or try to change USB cable.. to check if device is connected, did you use ">adb devices" ? or through eclipse ?

Comment: yes, i did both adb kill-server, then start server, devices... it won't show. On the other hand my nexus phone does appear ok that way. I believe the problem is that the device manager associates it with some MTP devices, rather then ADB.

Comment: if you think MTP is a problem try to install it again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7044/discussion-between-mohammed-and-user296516)

Answer (score 1):

try opening android sdk manager and tick the checkbox Google USB Driver.install and try to check if your device is recognized on adb

Answer (score 1):

My device was being recognized as a MTP, on windows 8 x64. It only worked after pointing manually to the .inf file and selecting "Android composite ADB interface".

Answer (score 0):

Use the automated ADB driver installer here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1488822

(You'll need to follow the manual instructions in the README.txt to force it to install as a Composite ADB Interface.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 64-bit version of Windows 8.x you'll need to disable "Driver Signature Verification" in addition to the steps Vijay C has listed. Otherwise Windows will display an error message saying that the driver is invalid or has been tampered with.

Instruction on how to disable the driver signature verification can be found here:
http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved with these steps.

If don't work with Vijay C's answer:

1 - Go to device manager. 
2 - Select your tablet. 
3 - Right click and update software. 
4 - When updating click "Allow choosing from my device drivers list on my computer" 
5 - Select "ADB Testing Interface driver..."